# How do you do "wrap_content" (Android XML syntax) in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am an Android developer trying to learn iOS development in Swift. I was wondering how you achieve "wrap_content" in Xcode. Any ideas? What are the variables to change in the attribute inspector?

Comment: If you're referring to text wrapping to the next line, then suppose you have a `UILabel *myLabel` then you can do `myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;` and `myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;`

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

The [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) state that `wrap_content`:

> tells your view to size itself to the dimensions required by its content.

This sounds analogous to what Apple calls the [*intrinsic content size*](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2151265&seqNum=7). They detail how to configure it in the attribute inspector [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/SettingaCustomViewsPlaceholderIntrinsicContentSize.html).

---

To override the intrinsic content size of a `UIView` (such as a `UILabel` or a `UIButton`), you would simply have to override [`UIView`'s `intrinsicContentSize()` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/intrinsicContentSize).

Comment: what do I do if I want to just make the height wrap_content (intrinsic content size). I am writing this in Swift by the way.

Comment: @andy7586 You have to understand that the *intrinsic content size* is the size that an element (let's say, a `UIButton`) naturally wants to be. This, for a button, would be based on the font size of the label (assuming you've set it with a title), and the `titleEdgeInsets`—essentially the padding between the text and the button. So, to tweak just the intrinsic content *height* of a button—you could change the font size, or modify the `titleEdgeInsets`. That, or subclass the `UIButton` in your own custom class that overrides the `intrinsicContentSize()` method, changing the height.

Comment: Your link **They detail how to configure it in the attribute inspector here.** is dead

Answer (score 4):

Try following code that fits textView's frame according to it's contained data-

```
let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
var newFrame = textView.frame
newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
textView.frame = newFrame;
```

Answer (score 1):

u can do this in storyboard

1. select the UIView*
2. in Attribute Inspector select Line Breaks
3. choose Word Wrap

be sure no other constraint defined for the view which limit the width!

Comment: This only works on text, wrap_content on Android works on all view elements.

Comment: I don't get it; how would word wrap constrain the height correctly?

Comment: As far as I know, it's the default behavior for text and button views, and if there are conflicting constraints you should set priority, or set width or height of the views.

Comment: Enabling word wrapping for labels causes exactly the opposite behavior of what `wrap_content` on Android does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick with constraints to achieve wrap-content. For example :

```
let maximumWidth = frame / 4  //For example
yourView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: maximumWidth).isActive = true
```

The "maximumWidth" depends on your UI and your design and you can change it.

Also, you should set "lineBreakMode" in StoryBoard or in code like :

```
yourBtn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping //For UIButton or
yourTxt.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping //For UITextView
```